# Swap Images With jQuery hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an img tag with following details: id="hover1" src="hello.png"

Using two separate buttons, I'm able to swap images with following jQuery:

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
$('#hover1').attr('src', 'hello_hover.png');
});

$('#button2').click(function(){
$('#hover1').attr('src', 'hello.png');
});
```

However, when I try to swap images with the following code nothing seems to happen.

```
$('#hover1').hover(function(){
$(this).attr('src', 'hello_out.png');
}, function(){
$(this).attr('src', 'hello.png');
});
```

The code looks ok to me. What is causing it to fail? Please help me out.
I'm using jQuery 2.1.0 , Mozilla 26.0, Windows7.
Thanks.

Comment: seems correct, can you provide a jsfiddle please ?

Comment: you most likely didnt wait till DOM is fully loaded and atatch the handlers to non existent elements. open developer console and see if you get errors for elements being undefined. if yes, put your code in a function that runs after DOM load

Comment: looks good to me, only difference i see is, that you use two different image-paths in your two examples...

Comment: @Banana I'm using code right at the bottom in body tag. There are no errors in the developer console. Other code works fine; only this one is acting up for some unknown reason. Still stuck.

Comment: Ok, found the culprit.I had set up a custom function to trap errors. In order to test its validity, I also made a call to an undefined function. This call was somewhere in the middle of the file. All the code before that call was working fine. Only the code that was after that call was not working. I've shifted that call to the bottom. Sanity restored.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('a img').hover( function () {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/\.jpg/, 'yourImageName.jpg') );
    });
```

let see this ..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Works well for me here... try using this JQuery code, and waiting to run it until the document is done loading :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hover1').hover(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', 'hello_hover.png');
    }, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', 'hello.png');
    });
});
```

Working Fiddle :

### http://jsfiddle.net/st7sM/1/

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's not what are you looking for but maybe it could help 
Why you don't only use CSS?
**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/st7sM/2/)** the fiddle

```
#hover1{
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/4');
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
}
#hover1:hover{
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But as you can see its a very simple function. It's supposed to work. Right now I'm just testing and learning. Pretty soon I'm gonna need to use it some where. What am I gonna do then? Thanks again for taking time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

To swap images easily, you can use the open source library bootstrap-spacer via NPM

```
npm install swapimagesonhover
```

or you can visit the github page:

```
https://github.com/chigozieorunta/swapimagesonhover
```

Using the above library, the data-img attribute is used to attach the second image of your choice you would want swapped. Once this is done, simply add your swim class to the image element and you're good to go (make sure jQuery script is included, it requires it to work properly).

Here's a sample below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="swapimagesonhover.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="swapimagesonhover.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="image1.jpg" data-img="image2.jpg" class="swim"/>
</body>
```